# Writing to Joomla database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm a front end dev, so my PHP is a bit lacking and I'm stuck.
I'm trying to write some data from a form into the Joomla database.
It's only an email address so not complicated. I've created a form and a table in the database to hold the email addresses. However I can't get it to write to the database and I'm not sure what I'm missing.
I'm not sure what classes I need to include in my code. I'm including joomla/factory so I'm not getting an error telling me the JFactory is not an object, but I don't know if I need to include anything else.

Here's my PHP code:

```
$emailAdd = $_POST['email'];

require_once ('../../libraries/joomla/factory.php');

$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "INSERT INTO '#__pdfemails' ('emailaddress')
    VALUES ('thevalue')";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

I don't get any kind of error at all, but it's not writing to the database.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Which error are you getting? Are you getting warnings?

Comment: Oh, and I inserted "thevalue" into VALUES just to see if it would write that, but it doesn't :-/

Comment: @hakre I'm not getting any errors at all, which is just adding to my confusion.

Comment: What does `$db->query();` return? And aside: don't use `=&` for object assignments, just write `=` w/o the `&`, you don't want a reference/alias here.

Comment: You don't get errors, or errors are simply not shown? If you make a syntax error on purpose does it shows?

Comment: @hakre Sorry to be n00b, but how do I see what $db->query(); is returning?

Comment: @DamienPirsy Errors do show if I make a syntax error, I'm simply not getting any errors, but it's still not working.

Comment: For example with `var_dump($db->query());` or by assigning the return value to a variable: `$result = $db->query();` and then using `var_dump($result);` (better for debugging).

Comment: @hakre It's still showing nothing. I've added `echo $emailAdd;` above the `require_once ('../../libraries/joomla/factory.php');` and it's showing the value that's being submitted in the form, but then not doing anything else. Could the problem be with the `require_once ('../../libraries/joomla/factory.php');` line? Without it I get the Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found, so it must be including the class, but not getting past that?

Comment: @hakre `$db->query();` is returning bool(false).

Comment: Your query failed. Read the API documentation of the DB object and look how you can retrieve the error message.

Comment: @hakre said exactly what I was thinking when I saw the query - try to run it directly in the DB - I'm pretty sure you'll find the error.

Comment: @hakre @alfasin Thanks guys. I tried it without using the API, connecting to the DB and writing the SQL query and it worked. Seemed to be a problem with the syntax  `$query = "INSERT INTO #__pdfemails (emailaddress)` theres quotes around emailadress in the example above. I removed them and it works.

Comment: @toby_lh - please answer your own question and "accept" the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your SQL. This:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO '#__pdfemails' ('emailaddress')
VALUES ('thevalue')";
```

should be this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO '#__pdfemails' (emailaddress)
VALUES ('thevalue')";
```

Note the lack of single-quotes around the column name.

If you ever get an error like this again, try executing the SQL directly in MySQL first. In a Joomla environment, there can be many points at which errors get 'hidden'. That's very sensible for a live site, although you should be able to configure a development site to show SQL errors to ease troubleshooting.

Comment: BTW, I partially agree with Brent re: the holes in your code. I'm not in complete agreement over getting a third-party attachment, though - do whatever makes most sense, but make sure you do it properly!

Comment: Thanks @Bobby Jack. That was it. Working fine now.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an easy answer for you - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

There 2 pages of form builders. I know Chronoforms (it's free too) will do exactly what you want. You can be done in under 10 minutes including install time. Plus you will get validation and other functions like data sanitation without having to write it yourself.

Judging from the code you posted, you're headed down a road to XSS and SQL injection attacks. Do yourself a favor and get an extension that works.

Comment: Thanks @Brent Friar, but I'm not sure Chrono Forms will do what I need. I've used it before a few times too, but for this I need to take an email address to allow for a PDF download, then set a cookie to remember the user has already submitted their email, so I need to make it bespoke of that purpose. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: ChronoForms will absolutely do that. There is even a custom form action you can download from the forums from GreyHead that makes it easy to add a static attachment to an outgoing email. Then you just use the custom code event to set the cookie. Everything else is built in.